# Dynamic reference line based on filtered date [TABLEAU PUBLIC]

Tags: tableau-api

I'm creating a graph with oil prices, where in dashboard you select one single day from the past to return oil price from that day. I'd like to have a reference line in the graph with median prices (on the bottom of dashboard) which should be based on selected date (it should simply present the horizontal line equaling to oil price from that day).

You can find this dashboard here:

https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Barrelofoildata/oil_dashboard?:embed=y&:display_count=no

Thanks!